# Install Gitlab on AWS

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

My company has a master codebase and several instances of the same codebase i.e company.com/instance1, company.com/instance2, company.com/instance3 and so on running on AWS and a mysql database.

I thought it would help if we install gitlab on AWS as it would simplify our overall developement process. Is this a good idea ?.

I am confused as to whether we have to install centOS on AWS to install gitlab or does gitlab will work on AWS without centos.

I am puzzled as in my local centos system i have installed gitlab locally and i have trouble setting up URL's.

The users need to type company.com/instance to get what is required and already people have started using it on AWS.

May be i have do CI and deploy the code on AWS ? How does this work?

Will gitlab work well in LAMP environment on an already existing AWS server instance? how to go about the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitLab should work as an [Amazon Machine Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image)

As explained in [GitLab CE AWS AMI](https://about.gitlab.com/aws/):

> [Search for GitLab CE X.Y (X.Y represent version number) under Community AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?searchTerms=GitLAb%20ce%208.11&page=1&ref_=nav_search_box).
>   The latest version of GitLab CE will be fetched on first boot.
>
> Launch a [**`c4.large`** instance](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-new-c4-instances/) with open ports for ssh, http and https.
>
> SSH into the instance with ubuntu@your-instance, edit the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file to your needs, and run:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

> Visit the public IP in a browser and sign in as the default user

```
username: root
password: 5iveL!fe
```

Comment: Well, you find a ton of different images there (Bitnami, Turnkey, nonames, ...), how do I know which one is the right one?

Comment: @CherryDT not sure, you will have to test them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use AMI, you can just use package provided by Gitlab to install and run it.

Reference: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604

Comment: And here is another example that's straightforward:  https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-ce-on-centos-7/